# Get the grand parents of html element using jquery .parentsUntil() or parent()

Tags: jquery, dom

Am using a accordion in which the click function is made for `grand child` while clicking it has to add a `class` to its `grand parent`

i know the `parent()` method is used to direct parent.and more am not clear with `parentsUntil()` then how to get reach the grand parent??

my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vivekranth/8Dh3s/1/)

on there while clicking `'.accordion > .head > h1 > span.httpmethod > a.trigger'` the class `.active` has to add to its grand parent `.accordion` check that fiddle and give me some ideas. if the questions is repeated means am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `.closest()`

```
$('.accordion a.trigger').click(function(){
     $(this).closest('.accordion').toggleClass('active'); 
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fYNuk/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use $(".selector").parent().parent(). Only problem with this is when the dom structure changes you have to change the amount of .parent() you use too.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use eq (http://api.jquery.com/eq/) filter to filter 3rd parent from the clicked target element. Check out this snippet!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".trigger").bind("click", function(event) {
            var el = $(event.currentTarget);
            var parent = el.parents().eq(3);
            parent.toggleClass("active", true);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="head">
            <h1>
                <span class="httpmethod">
                    <a class="trigger">Link 1</a>
                </span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="head">
            <h1>
                <span class="httpmethod">
                    <a class="trigger">Link 2</a>
                </span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="head">
            <h1>
                <span class="httpmethod">
                    <a class="trigger">Link 3</a>
                </span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```